# Working through Practical Common lisp, how to get started

Tags: common-lisp

I want to setup a common lisp environment to write non-trivial programs. I have been learning common lisp by typing in code at the REPL.

I wish to start projects, therefore I want to code in a text editor and compile that file so that I can make changes and save changes in that file.

I have tried Lisp in a box. I have tried Portacle too. Suggest IDE/ editors that can help me write non-trivial programs. Please give a step-by-step walkthrough to setup lisp environment as I have tried numerous ways but hadn't successfully completed a project. You can also point out any tutorial/ book/ blog about any  IDE.

Comment: Many people use Emacs, slime and sbcl. Some people use vim. If you are willing to pay, you can get Allegro or LispWorks which each come with an IDE (similarly to Racket coming with drRacket except you pay for it)

Answer (score 4):

The [Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook) has you covered:

- [editor support](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html): Emacs (&Portacle), Vim, Lem, Atom, Sublime, notebooks (jupyter notebook, Darkmatter), and advanced REPLs (cl-repl).
- [getting started](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html) - step by step explanations.

Comment: Thanks a ton! started working on the project through portacle and emacs

Comment: Nice ! If something's missing that's considered a bug ! (now you're invited to mark this answer as the accepted one in order to resolve this question).